# How to get address of templated WTL class object C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, wtl

I inherited some C++ code and it has me stumped.

Have a class declared like so.

```
class CIENavigator :  public CWTLAxControl<CIENavigator,IWebBrowser2>
{
public:
```

Instance like so

```
CIENavigator CIE;
CIENavigator * pCIE = &CIE;
```

Gets this compile error

```
1>.\IENavigator.cpp(446) : error C2440: 'initializing' :
          cannot convert from 'IWebBrowser2 **' to 'CIENavigator *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires 
          reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Although CIE is declared as CIENavigator, it thinks the type of &CIE to be IWebBrowser2 **

If I force the cast like so:

```
CIENavigator CIE;
CIENavigator * pCIE = (CIENavigator *) &CIE;
```

It compiles, but the pointer is indeed the wrong pointer.

I note the class name appears in the declaration of itself, but I don't know what the significance of that is.
I'm not up on Class templates.

How do I get the right CIENavigator object (CIE) address?

Answer (score 1):

`CWTLAxControl` has probably an overloaded `operator&`, to circumvent use [Boost.AddressOf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof).